# Network information from macOS command line

Tags: macos, command-line, mac

What is the command in mac os X to get:

1. The TCP ports numbers on which my computer is listening, ignoring when its listening to itself (127.0.0.1)
2. My routing table.

Answer (score 1):

1. `netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep -v ' 127\.0\.0\.1\.'`
2. `netstat -rn`

Note that the routing table will include the hardware addresses of other hosts on local networks (i.e. the ARP and neighbor discovery cache entries), as well as entries for inactive interfaces (e.g. tunnel virtual interfaces).